# How to extract non-numeric special character values in a large Series object?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is an extended question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58655386/how-to-remove-error-values-in-large-df-with-1000-columns).

I'm working on a large dataset and it seems to be very messy containing random strings here and there with no order. I would like to check on these values column wise without printing the numeric values of those columns. For example if `df.Col` is a `float` object but has strings such as #$, ^%#, etc., is there a way to view/print only those?

EDIT:

For example I have a column `Client_Income`.

```
print(str(df["Client_Income"].name).upper())
print("No. of unique values:", df["Client_Income"].nunique())
print(df["Client_Income"].unique())

CLIENT_INCOME
No. of unique values: 1217
['6750' '20250' '18000' ... '13140' '9764.1' '12840.75']
```

While this shows that the column could be purely `float` deliberately converted to `object`, when I do `.astype("float16")` for example, I get the error `Cannot convert to float: '$'`. There are other columns that contains values such as 'XNA', '##', etc.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Added last secttion.

Comment: So need `pd.to_numeric(df['Client_Income'], errors='coerce').dropna()` ?

Comment: Is there a way to print out only the error values? For example if a column has strings ## and @&, then is it possible to only print out those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert values to numeric and if failed is created `NaN`s, so then filter by `NaN` in converted `Series` and non NaNs by original column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Client_Income':['6750', '20.250', '18000','XNA', '##45', '#4.5#', np.nan],

})


s = pd.to_numeric(df['Client_Income'], errors='coerce')
out1 = df.loc[s.isna() & df['Client_Income'].notna(), 'Client_Income']
print (out1)
3      XNA
4     ##45
5    #4.5#
Name: Client_Income, dtype: object
```